# Asp.net MVC take time to load css and modernizr after cache clear

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance

After clearing the cache, the site takes long time to load. I am not sure why the css and js libs are taking long to load.

I can use CDNs but it is way to long. The html loads fine. The site is pre-compiled and only cache is getting cleared and load time increases considerably.

I have seen jquery, mordernizr and/or bootstrap take a long time to load.

Browsers: Firefox 60.0.1, Chrome, IE 11

I see the time spent is mostly waiting and if proxy connections (max) is the issue then all other calls combined must exceed the waiting time.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: only think i can think of... is that its just slow as you have some other file which is large which is taking all the bandwidth when trying to download those resources and just makes it look like those are the issue.

Comment: oooo... are you doing something weird with your connections routing like processing all requires, including css and js, as maybe its related to session stuff. yes i know this is all a long shot but yours seems very odd.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Are there any tools which can identify the reason of long delay?

Comment: break point on begin request.... and see what being processed. like i say if all your request as being processed... it may be attaching sessions to them.. well processing them like they do.... which means if you had a few in a row it would cause delays. confirm that css and js are not being processed and are just served.